# Avoid the problem with recurring tasks

Tags: apex

I am looking to find a work around and solution of the problem  “Error: You cannot reassign a recurring task occurrence.” as I'm assigned to transfer many tasks and most of them are recurring.

Could you please suggest and help me find an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to clone your list of recurring Tasks, assign the desired new owner to the cloned Tasks, then insert your cloned list as new Tasks, then set the `RecurrenceEndDateOnly` of the existing recurring Tasks to `Today()` and finally update that existing list of recurring Tasks. That should allow those tasks to come to a conclusion at the same time while creating replacements that will belong to the new owner you want them assigned to.

From the Object Reference:

> - When you change the value of RecurrenceEndDateOnly to an earlier date (for example, from January 20th to January
>     10th), all open task occurrences in the series with the ActivityDate value greater than the new end date value are deleted.
>     Other open and closed task occurrences in the series are not affected.

You'll also want to be aware of this behavior:

> - When you change the RecurrenceStartDateOnly field or the recurrence pattern, all open tasks occurrences in the
>     series are deleted and new open task occurrences are created based on the new recurrence pattern. The recurrence pattern
>     is determined by the following fields: RecurrenceType, RecurrenceTimeZoneSidKey, RecurrenceInterval,
>     RecurrenceDayOfWeekMask, RecurrenceDayOfMonth, RecurrenceInstance, and RecurrenceMonthOfYear.

Because of the above, unless you want to calculate the correct new start date (because of the recurrences that have likely happened since the original start), I would be very cautious of resetting the `RecurrenceStartDateOnly` field when you insert the new Tasks as it likely won't be Today(). Yet, that would also be the proper way to do it.

Comment: Actually what I would like to achieve is this:

If for instance there is a merchant with OwnerID = A.

In this Merchant we have two tasks Task1 and Task2.

The assignee of Task1 is user B (Task1.OwnerID = B).

The assignee of Task2 is user C (Task2.OwnerID = C).

When the OwnerID of the Merchant is changed to K

then the assingee of Task1 and Task2 are also changed to K and Task1.OwnerID = K and Task2.OwnerID = K.

I would like to avoid that.

Comment: I strive to achieve the following result:

The OwnerID of the Merchant to be K

but

the Taks1.OwnerID = B

and

the Task2.OwnerID = C

In other words when the Merchant.OwnerID is changed, the assignees of the tasks must remain the same and should not be changed.

Is that possible and how it can be achived.

Comment: How are you currently reassigning the Tasks? If through a trigger, you can test for `task.IsRecurrence == true`. If it's true, then you remove it from your list of tasks that you're reassigning ownership on.

Comment: Ok but I still do not see how this will resolve the case. 
What I am trying to achieve is the following: 
For instance merchant with owner A (merchant.ownerId = A) and two tasks inside the merchant: Task1, Task2. Assignees of the tasks are users B and C, i.e. Task1.ownerId = B, Task2.ownerId = C. 
After merchant owner is changed from A to K in the user interface of SalesForce, then assignees of the tasks must NOT be changed and they should remain users B and C (and not to be assigned to anyone else).

Comment: What you're saying is that workflow is trying to change the owner? Or is a standard page trying to change the owner? If the latter, you probably need to create a Before Update trigger on Account that checks for recurring tasks being reassigned and assigns them back to their current owner so they don't get reassigned. Check your debug logs to see how it's happening now and when/where your error message is occurring. I'm guessing it occurs when attempt is made to update the Task or else in workflow.